# How to filter out duplicates in powershell loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a loop to check for sensitive users having processes on computers that they should not. I am trying to figure out a way to only report back unique users who are on there so the list would look like paul,sarah,tom for instance instead of paul,paul,sarah,tom,sarah,paul etc...I am leaving the etra information like process names/ids in case I need more information so I can reuse the function.

```
  $AdminUsers = get-content SomeUsers.txt


  $WmiArguments = @{
    'Class' = 'Win32_process'
}
$processes = Get-WMIobject @WmiArguments | ForEach-Object {
    $Owner = $_.getowner();
    $Process = New-Object PSObject
    $Process | Add-Member Noteproperty 'ComputerName' $Computer
    $Process | Add-Member Noteproperty 'ProcessName' $_.ProcessName
    $Process | Add-Member Noteproperty 'ProcessID' $_.ProcessID
    $Process | Add-Member Noteproperty 'Domain' $Owner.Domain
    $Process | Add-Member Noteproperty 'User' $Owner.User
    $Process
}
ForEach ($Process in $Processes) {
    if ($AdminUsers -Contains $Owner.User) {  

    $somevar = 'User: ' + $Owner.User + ' found on ' + $Computer
    
    set-content -path somelog.txt -value $somevar 
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into Group-Object?

Comment: ... or `$processes | select user | sort -unique`